# Save and Display POST request from external website in LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, post, model-view-controller, laravel-blade

I'm handling a POST request from an external website I am able to store the data but how do I display it on the blade.

Controller:

```
public function parse(Request $request)
    {
        $files = File::create([
            'Data1'      => $request->input('Data1'),
            'Data2'     => $request->input('Data2'),
            'Data3'       => $request->input('Data3'),
        ]);

        return view('fileview');
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::any('fileview', 'App\Http\Controllers\FilesController@Files')->name('parse');
```

Blade:

```
{{ $Data1 }}
```

EDIT:

I'm receiving this error from my returnURL but the data stores perfectly

`Trying to get property 'profile' of non-object (View: D:\Systems\final\resources\views\partials\dash-sidenav.blade.php) {"exception":"[object] (Facade\\Ignition\\Exceptions\\ViewException(code: 0): Trying to get property 'profile' of non-object (View: D:\\Systems\\final\ esources\\views\\partials\\dash-sidenav.blade.php) at D:\\Systems\\final\ esources\\views/partials/dash-sidenav.blade.php:4)`

dash-sidenav.blade.php

```
@if ((Auth::User()->profile) && Auth::user()->profile->avatar_status == 1)
                                <img src="{{ Auth::user()->profile->avatar }}" alt="{{ Auth::user()->name }}" class="user-avatar-nav">
                            @else
                            <img src="{{asset('images/mascot.jpg')}}" alt="" class="user-avatar-nav" >
                            @endif
```

Comment: Try to change `Auth::user()->profile->avatar_status == 1` to `Auth::user()->profile['avatar_status'] == 1`, your error is not related to display POST request. This error is `profile` is not an object while you are trying access `avatar_status` as an object.

Comment: tried that and still throws same error.

Comment: Could you add `dd(Auth::user())` in your controller and update the response please?

Comment: I think I found the problem, the session is lost when I'm receiving the POST request from external website. I tried commenting the error above, and another error was shown saying ```Trying to get property 'username' of non-object```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ty editing your controller and add `->with()` like this:

```
public function parse(Request $request)
{
    $files = File::create([
        'Data1'      => $request->input('Data1'),
        'Data2'     => $request->input('Data2'),
        'Data3'       => $request->input('Data3'),
    ]);

    return view('fileview')->with('Data1', $request->input('Data1'));
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now ```Trying to get property 'profile' of non-object (View: D:\Systems\final\resources\views\partials\dash-sidenav.blade.php) {"exception":"[object] (Facade\\Ignition\\Exceptions\\ViewException(code: 0): Trying to get property 'profile' of non-object (View: D:\\Systems\\final\ esources\\views\\partials\\dash-sidenav.blade.php) at D:\\Systems\\final\ esources\\views/partials/dash-sidenav.blade.php:4)```

Comment: I'll need more context, nothing you have posted references a "profile" property.